# VBA - Trouble with Loop Structure for File Searching and Copying

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to develop a macro on one of my spreadsheets that will take the value of Column B (2502-13892-33 for example), starting at Row 3, and search the source folder listed in column A for that file (using Wildcards before and after the value in column B. Once it finds that file, it needs to use FileCopy to copy the file into the Destination Folder listed in Column C, but only after renaming the file in the form of "Column E"_"Original Filename (A252_2502-13892-33 for example).

I think I have worked out the code to make this work because when I tested it, it functioned exactly like I expected it to, found the file, copied it to the new destination with the PREFIX from column E and the underscore added to the filename. The problem is that it just stops after the first file, which leads me to believe something is wrong with the structure of my loop.

My code is as follows:

```
    Sub MoveFiles()
Dim SourcePath As String
Dim DestPath As String
Dim PartNum As String
Dim PLISN As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim filename As String

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To LastRow
    PLISN = Cells(i, "E").Value
    PartNum = Cells(i, "B").Value

    If Right(Cells(i, "A").Value, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
        SourcePath = Cells(i, "A").Value & Application.PathSeparator
    Else
        SourcePath = Cells(i, "A").Value
    End If

    If Right(Cells(i, "C").Value, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
        DestPath = Cells(i, "C").Value & Application.PathSeparator
    Else
        DestPath = Cells(i, "C").Value
    End If

    If Dir$(SourcePath & "*" & PartNum & "*") = "" Then
        Cells(i, "D").Value = "Source file does not exist."
    ElseIf Dir$(DestPath & PLISN & "_" & "*" & PartNum & ".pdf") <> "" Then
        Cells(i, "D").Value = "File already exists."
    Else
        filename = Dir$(SourcePath & "*" & PartNum & "*" & ".pdf")
        'Copy the file
        FileCopy SourcePath & filename, DestPath & PLISN & "_" & filename
        Cells(i, "D").Value = "File Copied to new location"
    End If



Next i
     End Sub
```

Comment: Have you run through it in the debugger (F8) one line at a time to see exactly where it's stopping?

Comment: Using the debugger would help you greatly. Alternatively, (temporarily) insert some `debug.print` statements to view the progress of your processing -- such as if you add a `PathSeparator` and when you start/stop the `FileCopy`. In particular, check the value of `i` and the value of `LastRow`. My guess is that `LastRow=3` and your loop is only running once because that's what it's been told to do.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion FreeMan. By stepping through it like you said, it became clear to me that the DestinationPath was getting a value of just "\" on the second and third times through the loop.

Comment: Accidently split my comments. But I meant to continue on and say that I had accidentally left my DestinationPath blank for the 2nd and 3rd lines of the excel sheet. That was what was giving me just the "\" as the destination path. Seems to be working properly now. Thanks!

Comment: The debugger is your friend!  You may want to post your comment and updated code as an answer, then come back to mark it as accepted. That will help the next person who's looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

I had accidentally left my DestinationPath blank for the 2nd and 3rd lines of the excel sheet. That was what was giving me just the "\" as the destination path. Seems to be working properly now.

As someone mentioned below in one of the comments, stepping through my code in the debugger was extremely helpful to solving this problem. My final code has some structural changes, in that I no longer have columns for SourcePath and DestPath, and instead use a folder dialog box to have the user select both of those.

The code for selecting my Source and Destination Folders:

```
    Sub SourceFolder()
Dim lCount As Long
Dim rCount As Long

SourcePath = vbNullString
DestPath = vbNullString

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = OpenAt
    .Title = "Source Path"
    .Show
    For lCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
        SourcePath = .SelectedItems(lCount)
        MsgBox (SourcePath)
    Next lCount
End With
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = OpenAt
    .Title = "Destination Path"
    .Show
    For rCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
        DestPath = .SelectedItems(rCount)
        MsgBox (DestPath)
    Next rCount
End With
    End Sub
```

The code for actually going out to the SourcePath, searching for the filename located in Column A (including with wildcards before and after), copying it to the DestinationPath, and renaming it with ColumnB's Value, followed by an underscore, and then ColumnA's Value is as follows:

```
    Option Explicit
Public SourcePath As String
Public DestPath As String
Dim PartNum As String
Dim PLISN As String



    Sub MoveFiles()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim filename As String

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To LastRow
    PLISN = Cells(i, "B").Value
    PartNum = Cells(i, "A").Value

    If Right(SourcePath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
        SourcePath = SourcePath & Application.PathSeparator
    Else
        SourcePath = SourcePath
    End If

    If Right(DestPath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
        DestPath = DestPath & Application.PathSeparator
    Else
        DestPath = DestPath
    End If

    If Dir$(SourcePath & "*" & "*" & PartNum & "*") = "" Then
        Cells(i, "C").Value = "Source file does not exist."
    ElseIf Dir$(DestPath & PLISN & "_" & "*" & PartNum & "*" & ".pdf") <> "" Then
        Cells(i, "C").Value = "File already exists."
    Else
        filename = Dir$(SourcePath & "*" & PartNum & "*" & ".pdf")
        'Copy the file
            FileCopy SourcePath & filename, DestPath & PLISN & "_" & filename
            Cells(i, "C").Value = "File Copied to new location"
    End If



Next i
    End Sub
```